# how to read values of nested objects with predefined string

Tags: javascript

i have objects which have hold x amounts of nested objects:

```
let obj = {
 nestedObject: {
  key: value
 }
}
```

or

```
let obj2 = {
 nestedObject2: {
  nestedObject3: {
   key2: value2 
  }
 }
}
```

etc.

Getting the values of both those objects is not that difficult:

```
obj.nestedObject.key 
obj['nestedObject']['key]
```

or

```
obj2.nestedObject2.nestedObject3.key2
obj2['nestedObject2']['nestedObject3']['key2']
```

This should happen dynamically though which is what I don't know how to achieve.
I get random objects with the structure above and also a string which tells me where to find the values. For obj2 in the example above I would get the string

> "nestedObject2.nestedObject3.key2"

How do I use this information to get the proper value? The two strategies above don't work anymore and something easy like

> obj2['nestedObject2.nestedObject3.key2']

doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: All you have to do is remove the single quotes. `obj2[nestedObject2.nestedObject3.key2]`

Comment: can you use lodash `get` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Comment: @sterlingArcher no, that doesnt make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by the delimiter of a period character, and then reduce to find the appropriate property, going down a level on every iteration.

```
str.split(".").reduce((a, v) => (a = a[v], a), parent_object);
```

```js
let o = {
    nestedObject2: {
      nestedObject3: {
        key2: "a key"
      }
    }
  },
  str = "nestedObject2.nestedObject3.key2";

let ref = str.split(".").reduce((a, v) => (a = a[v], a), o);

console.log(ref);
```